# Where to define shell aliases in configs for projects in tmuxinator?

Tags: tmux, alias

I define Bash aliases in my `~/.tmuxinator/*.yml` files like this:

```
pre_window: alias cc=heh/path/that;alias ccc='cc clean; clear; cc' ;alias selenium-restart=bin/docker/restart-selenium-chrome ;alias yii=bin/docker/yii/yii
```

Is there a better way? It works, but, obviously, it is not convenient to add them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this ticket in tmuxinator's issue tracker titled: ["pre" option not using zsh options, alias, configuration (running as sh) #286](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/286) it looks like you'd either do it as a `pre:` or a `pre_window:`. The OP to that ticket was trying `pre:`

```
pre:
    - setopt clobber
    - source ~/projects/auv/devel/setup.zsh
    - stt
```

and getting this error:

```
> mux start auv-core
sh: 13: setopt: not found
sh: 13: source: not found
sh: 13: stt: not found
arranging in: main-vertical
arranging in: main-vertical
[exited]
```

and one of the [developers says this](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/286#issuecomment-108923555):

> Things like setopt, source and alias are all built in shell commands and don't make sense in a shell script.
>
> Your only option would be to put them in pre_window so send-keys is used in each window / pane.

Based on this comment I think your only option is to use `pre_window:` as you're doing. You might want to take a different tactic rather than list all the aliases in a `pre_window:` directly, put them in a file:

```
$ cat ~/my_aliases
alias cc=heh/path/that
alias ccc='cc clean; clear; cc'
alias selenium-restart=bin/docker/restart-selenium-chrome
alias yii=bin/docker/yii/yii
```

and have a `pre_window:` like this:

```
pre_window: source ~/my_aliases
```

But your approach looks consistent with how the project intends you to use `pre_window:` at the very least.

Comment: I didn't realize for some reason that I can put commands in separate list items for `pre`/`pre_window`, thanks!

Comment: By the way, what I'm doing is what your post suggests to be impossible.  Bash aliases in `pre_window` work fine.

Comment: @jojman - no you can put aliases in `pre_window` you can't put them in `pre` is what the thread stated.